# overriding compile method in squeak

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

How can i override the method (of behavior):

```
  compile: code notifying: requestor trailer: bytes ifFail: failBlock
```

in the new function (that overrides compile of Behavior) I need to compile the method in the object "code". Do I need to declare it as a class method?

and also, is code (which contains the method to be compiled) a String type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is confusing is that the browser does not show the parallel class-side hierarchy...

You know that true is an instance of class True, so if you send a message to true, it must be understood by it's class True, or one of its superclasses. We can use a browser for browsing that set of messages:

```
True browseHierarchy.
```

If we inquire the inheritance by repeatedly sending superclass messages, that closely matches what the hierarchy browser shows, so far so good :

```
True superclass -> Boolean.
Boolean superclass -> Object.
Object superclass -> ProtoObject.
ProtoObject superclass -> nil.
```

Now what if you send a message to the class True itself? It will be understood by it's class, True class (which is a metaclass `True class class == Metaclass`).

But let's inquire the hierarchy of the metaclass True class :

```
True class superclass -> Boolean class.
Boolean class superclass -> Object class.
Object class superclass -> ProtoObject class.
ProtoObject class superclass -> Class.
Class superclass -> ClassDescription.
ClassDescription superclass -> Behavior.
Behavior superclass -> Object.
Object superclass -> ProtoObject.
ProtoObject superclass -> nil.
```

Ah Ah! It's deeper than what the browser shows...
Unsurprisingly, you find Class in this hierarchy, so as to satisfy this:

```
"True is a (kind of) class" (True isKindOf: Class) -> true.
```

Since True class inherits from Behavior, any method of Behavior is understood by all the instances of True class (normally, there is a single one, `True class soleInstance == True`).

So, back to the problem, when you want to add an instance-side method to true, you ask to its class to compile a new method:

```
True compile: 'asInt ^1'.
```

Now, true responds to this #asInt message:

```
(true respondsTo: #asInt) -> true.
```

You can then send to any instance of True (again, there should be a single one, `True initializedInstance == true`):

```
true asInt -> 1.
```

If you want to install a method at class side, that the class True responds to, then you ask to the metaclass, True class, or one of it's superclass:

```
Boolean class compile: 'soleInstance ^self initializedInstance'.
```

Now you can ask:

```
True soleInstance -> true.
```

The lesson is this one: if some tool (like the browser) is just showing a partial view of what an object is, responds to, inherits from, etc..., then try using another tool like:

```
True class explore.
```

And a more important lesson: you're in a live environment, so ultimately use the swiss knife tool - send a message, if it is not understood, some object will kindly tell you ;)

Now since I've mostly solved your homework, here is a harder problem for you: if you wanted to intercept the compilation of a method compiled at class side, where would you override #compile:...?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to know whether you should define it on the class side, why don't you try it and report back to us ;) That is the magic of a live, dymanic system - it's yours to experiment in!
2. Code is a string type - normally ByteString

Comment: in 3 it was my mistake.. I meant to say in the new function that overrides compile of Behavior

Comment: it's confusing.. but I think that Behavior is a meta class and therefor I should define it in the class side..

Comment: @Shiran _Behavior_ is a class, _Behavior class_ is a metaclass