# Overriding a method in behavior -smalltalk-

Tags: smalltalk

I have an object A in Smalltalk and I want to override a method specifically the method compile in the behavior.

my aim is to customize compile method by adding asserts before compiling a code.
I know that compile is found in the A class (up until behavior) but how can I use it ?

I have tried a lot of ways non are working, the last of what I did is :
I defined a method :

compile:code
        
        self class compile:code. "this is not working it tells me message not understood"

how can I do this ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386061/overriding-compile-method-in-squeak

Answer (score 2):

[Pharo] Try redefining the method #compile:classified:withStamp:notifying: on the class side of your class. In this new implementation combine the assertion code with the first parameter (which is the source code you are about to compile) and then delegate to super with the modified code.